# How do I use the -I option of du to ignore all files of a given type?

Tags: command-line, du

Hello I am running OS X.

I am trying to use du and the -I option to ignore all files of a given type. 
I am resorting to -I because OS X du doesnt include the "exclude" option.

Essentially I am trying to find the OS X equivalent to this command:

du -ah --exclude="*.txt" /directory/folder

Comment: `du ... | sed '/.*\.txt/d'` ? Good luck.

Comment: Hmmm, ended up settling on a solution using find and awk:                      find directory/ -name '*.xml' -exec du -k {} \; | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'

Comment: post your solution as an answer (with example output) and then accept it as the answer 48 hrs later (I think) to gain valuable reputation points! ;-) Use the `{}` formatting tool at the top left of the edit box for format data and code. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had luck on MacOS 10.15 with the following:

```
du -I System -I private -I Library
```